# How to tell when an OpenGL context is changed

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

When using opengl through lwjgl, when an opengl context is made unavailable by making no context current (using glfwMakeContextCurrent(0)), the opengl calls all return 0 as a result. This can lead to unexpected results and it is often hard to see where the problem is. Is there any way of telling when a context is switched using a callback or something, so that a proper error can be filed?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the `lwjgl` library uses several different APIs', including `GLFW`. If you are using the `GLFW` `API` to create contexts(or the library is, which it looks like it from their website), then you can request to receive the window that the context is currently bound to using:

```
glfwGetCurrentContext();
```

If this returns NULL, it is probably not currently bound to any window. You could implement this function in a glfwPollEvents() style callback(or something similar), and output an error message when it checks the contexts status.

Comment: How would I impliment this within the glfwPollEvents() method?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know Java well enough to know how exactly you could implement this. In C++, I would set up the methods I want to get polled for each specific object, by using the glfwSet<glfwtype> callbacks, and then when my object gets updated every loop, the method will get polled and updated along with the other methods I set.